# Cant echo a variable that is on the same page but different file

Tags: php, html, variables

I have included header.php and index.php on the same page.

The following can be found on the `header.php` file:

```
<?php 
    $pageName="home";
    if(is_page('47')){
       $pageName="services";}
    printVar($pageName);
?>

function printVar($v){ //on functions.php
    echo $v;
}
```

It prints out the var immediately after the if-statement and anywhere on header.php, but when I go to `index.php` it doesn't print.

```
<ul class="<?php printVar($pageName); //does not print out ?>">  
    <li class="home"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li class="services"><a href="/">Services</a></li>
    <li class="seminar"><a href="#">Seminar</a></li>
    <li class="contact last"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

How can I print this variable without moving everything to `index.php`?

Comment: Could you please show us the entire code of index.php, header.php and the specific error that come out?

Comment: @jeffrey that list is literally all that is on the index.php and header.php is similar. I tried to minimize the problem without any of the bulk and still there. If it helps at all, my website is built on wordpress

Comment: @Jeffrey and there is no error, it just doesn't print anything out as if the variable is empty. Therefore, it sounds like it is a scope problem, but I dont see how it would be

Comment: Do a `var_dump` of the variable that need to be printed. Also are you sure you set `error_reporting(E_ALL);` correctly?

Comment: var_dump didnt output anything. I dont know what error_reporting is or how to use it nor have I ever had to set it up before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to have

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
```

in your index.php file

read more about [get_header()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header) on wordpress function reference.

Comment: Your answer helped me figure out what was wrong. I am using the new version of the starkers theme and they have essentially two header.php(header and html-header) and I saw that they dont include the second header into the first or vice versa. I dont know if that makes any sense but thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding:

```
include("header.php");
include("functions.php");
```

to your index.php

Add:

```
include("header.php");
```

in functions.php

and add:

```
include("functions.php");
```

in header.php